# CSS, JS not display when I passing value Laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my route

```
 Route::get('/basic', 'LessonController@basic')->name('basic'); 
 Route::get('/basic/{id}', 'LessonController@show')->name('show');
```

I did when /basic its display but /basic/{id} its not display

Comment: Please edit your question and write your controller code

Comment: can you show us the route:list

Comment: show us your view

Comment: can I see your shoe method of LessonController class ?

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly because your importing Your CSS and Javascript. Write them like this in view when your are using parameters

css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

js

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in rout

```
Route::get('/eachbasic/{id}', 'LessonController@show')->name('eachbasic');
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but its still not working

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I fixed before!